# Remove double-click on dropdown link

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm not very knowledgeable in javascript. But I need a dropdown on a vertical menu that is pure javascript, so I copied/paste the script from W3: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown

and modified it to fit the page style. This menu needs to be on multiple pages, so it's also an html include. I got it to somewhat work, but you have to double click the drop-drop down in order to close it and this needs to be a single-click. I've been searching for a solution for a couple weeks now and still not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can't use jquery, bootstrap or any outside library since it's not connected to the internet.

HTML:

```
<div id="content"> 
<div class="topvert"> 
<div class="vertheader"> 
<span class="quicklinks">QUICK MENU LIST</span> 
</div>

<div class="vertbtn"> 
<div class="quick"> 
<a href="#">Menu Item</a>
</div>
<div class="quick"> 
<div class="drop-button active"><div onclick="myButton()">Drop down Menu Item 
</div></div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: block;">
<a href="#">Menu Item</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>       
</div>   
<div class="btmvert"> 
<div class="vertheader"> 
<span class="quicklinks">2ND HALF (HEADLINE) QUICK MENU</span> 
</div>       
<div class="vertbtn">

<div class="quick"> 
<a href="#">Menu Item</a>
</div>
<div class="vertbtn"> 
<a class="backhome" href="#">Back to Home Page</a>
</div>           
</div>       
</div>   
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Merras/pen/LYVjVVp)

Comment: See my answer below. Please let me know, was it helpful and did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on your `.drop-button` element, you have an inline `onClick()` attribute/event, AND inside the handler function (function myButton()) you you declare another eventListener on top of that.

You should just remove the `onclick="myButton()"` attribute all together, and then your JavaScript would look like this:

(Run code snippet)

There are a few different ways in JavaScript to declare event listeners. One way is Inline/HTML Event Handlers that you put inline on the HTML element like an attribute, ie- `<div onClick="handlerFunction">`  But the more modern, and more recommended way is using `addEventListener()` directly from your JavaScript.

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelector(".drop-button");

dropdown.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
   var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
   if (dropdownContent.style.display == "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
   } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display= "block";
   }
});
```

```css
#content {
  margin: 1.875em 0px 0.625em 0px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #002f6c;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.75em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.75em;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
 top: 9.375em;
}

.quick {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.quick a {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0.625em;
    padding-bottom: 0.625em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: calc(0.5vw + 0.5vh + 0.5vmin);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #888B8D;
}

.quick a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: #002F6C;
    background-color: #FFD300;
}

.topvert {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btmvert {
 width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btmverthome {
 width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vertheader {
 width: auto;
  padding: 2%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.vertbtn {
 width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.vertbtn :hover {
  background-color: #FFD300;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

a.backhome {
  font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: calc(0.5vw + 0.5vh + 0.5vmin);
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.backhome:hover {
 color: #002f6c;
 background-color: #FFD300;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

.quicklinks {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(0.5vw + 0.5vh + 0.5vmin);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.drop-button {
  padding-top: 0.625em;
  padding-bottom: 0.625em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(0.5vw + 0.5vh + 0.5vmin);
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: #888B8D;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.drop-button:hover {
  color: #002f6c;
  background-color: #FFD300;
}


.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}


.active {
  background-color: #06a7e0;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #b4e4f5;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #06a7e0;
}

.dropdown-container > a {
 background-color: #50c1e9;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #06a7e0;
}

a { 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
a:hover { 
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div id="content"> 
 <div class="topvert"> 
  <div class="vertheader"> 
   <span class="quicklinks">QUICK MENU LIST</span> 
  </div>   
  <div class="vertbtn"> 
   <div class="quick"> 
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
   </div>
   <div class="quick"> 
    <div class="drop-button active"><div>Drop down Menu Item 
    </div></div>
      <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: block;">
       <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>   
 </div>  
 <div class="btmvert"> 
  <div class="vertheader"> 
   <span class="quicklinks">2ND HALF (HEADLINE) QUICK MENU</span> 
  </div>   
  <div class="vertbtn">
   
   <div class="quick"> 
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
   </div>
   <div class="vertbtn"> 
    <a class="backhome" href="#">Back to Home Page</a>
   </div>    
  </div>   
 </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine when running the snippet above and I did as recommended - removed the onclick, changed the script to yours (inline between the <head> tags), but now it doesn't drop down at all anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: No, the JavaScript snippet can’t be in the head tag. It need to be below your HTML just before your closing </body> tag.

Comment: Otherwise, it Can be in the <head>, but then you would need to wrap the JavaScript in the ‘DOMcontentLoaded’ event. In this case it’s easier to just put it in <script> tags just before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: Or, your could put the JavaScript in a function like you had it before, called ‘myButton()’ or whatever. And put it in <script> tags in the <head>, and then on the opening <body> tag you put ‘<body onLoad=“myButton”>’

Comment: I placed the script before the </body> but the console caught a TypeError and can't ready the property 'addEventListener', so it didn't work. Then I tried to put the script in the <head> again w/ the added tag after <body> and we're back to square one, after the 'active' gets added to the <div>, it takes a double-click to open/close.

Comment: Hmm, did you copy and paste my js code exactly? Compare it closely. It should work in script tags, located just above the closing </body> tag. Check the first line, it should be, ‘var dropdown = document.querySelector(“.drop-button”);’ (notice the dot before ‘drop-button’

Comment: And did you remove the ‘onClick’ attribute from the .drop-button HTML tag? Just copy and paste the code exactly, it should work. It’s working in stackoverflow snippet, it’s working in a codepen.io example I made, it’s working in a local HTML file I made running in chrome, edge, & Firefox. There must be something you’re missing from my example.

Comment: Compare very very closely.. down to every little dot, quote, semicolon, etc. Better yet, just copy and paste exactly so you know it’s exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, I copied the script to the exact, removed the onclick as instructed and placed the script as recommended (bottom, before </body>). As I mentioned, the menu is also an html include, so I'm not sure if that affects the script you wrote. In which case, I even tried placing your script in the included menu html just to see if that would do the trick and it brought the script into the other html, but still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by “an HTML include”? How exactly are you including the HTML and what are you including it into?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Because this menu has to go into multiple pages, so to avoid editing each page that has this menu, we include it. Works fine - but would it affect the javascript you wrote?

Comment: Ahhh, yes that makes a big difference. Yes, it affects the javascript for the menu, because it's an issue with timing..  It's an asynchronous call to inject the menu, so the javascript that runs to control the menu needs to occur After the file is loaded and after the html is fully injected into the page.  The easiest fix for this is to go back to how you were calling the menu javascript with the inline `onclick` event.  Otherwise you would need to modify the injection script to call a callback function once the file has been fully injected.

Comment: I've made a full working codepen example for you using your injection script, with seperate `index.html` and `menu.html` files. It should show you how to fully get it working. https://codepen.io/melliatto/project/editor/ZvmWEM#0

Comment: Sir...you are pure genius! Thank you SO, SO, much!!

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm glad I could help! :)  Good luck! ;)